# php dynamically create multi dimensional array

Tags: php, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I am writing a php script to extract some data from a MYSQL db, then I want to take that data and store it into a two dimensional array. Thinking of it normally, if I use code like this

```
$test = array();
$test[0]=array();
$test[0]['hello']='hello';
$test[1]=array();
$test[1]['hello']='hello';
$test[2]=array();
$test[2]['hello']='hello';
print_r($test);
```

the output will be:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [hello] => hello ) [1] => Array ( [hello] => hello ) [2] =>
Array ( [hello] => hello ) )
```

which is how I want my output to be

so this is what I do in my script

So basically in my database I have table with standings for a women's league and the columns are

```
team_name, played, won, drawn, lost, for, against, points
```

All the connections have been taken care of successfully, below is my query

```
$get_ladies_query = "SELECT 
`team_name`, `played`, `won`, `drawn`, `lost`, `for`, `against`, `points` 
FROM `standings_ladies` order by pos";
```

An important point to not before I show the next code is that, there are 2 other standings tables, men_senior and men_intermediate with the same structure but obviously only the data changes, below are the two queries just incase

```
$get_mens_inter_query = "SELECT 
`team_name`, `played`, `won`, `drawn`, `lost`, `for`, `against`, `points` 
FROM `standings_men_inter` order by pos";

    $get_mens_senior_query = "SELECT 
`team_name`, `played`, `won`, `drawn`, `lost`, `for`, `against`, `points` 
FROM `standings_men_senior` order by pos";
```

Now I create 3 arrays which I want to hold standings seperately for the ladies, mens senior, mens intermediate

```
$standings_ladies = array();
$standings_men_inter = array();
$standings_men_senior = array();
```

The data I want displayed in the array is like so

```
array(0=>array(team_name,wins,drawn,lost,for,against,points)
1=>array(team_name,wins,drawn,lost,for,against,points)) and so on
```

Now since I wanted to create the multidimensional arrays of standings for all 3 categories, I could have run the queries in 3 separate while loops altough I thought, I could accomplish the same result in 1 and i felt it would help improve performance. If its better to use 3 while loops, please let me know, what I tried is below.

```
//I run the 3 queries and store them in the given variables
$result_mens_senior = mysqli_query($link,$get_mens_senior_query);
$result_mens_inter = mysqli_query($link,$get_mens_inter_query);
$result_ladies= mysqli_query($link, $get_ladies_query);

//I want to create 1 while loop so based of the results returned from the 3 
//queries so based on the results returned from the 3 queries, 
//I get the max number of times I want the query to run
$ladies_boundary = mysqli_num_rows($result_ladies);
$mens_senior_boundary = mysqli_num_rows($result_mens_senior);
$mens_inter_boundary = mysqli_num_rows($result_mens_inter);
$max_size = max(array($ladies_boundary,$mens_senior_boundary,$mens_inter_boundary));

//set an index to start from 0
$index = 0;

//I will only show the example for 1 of the arrays but you get an idea
that this issue will occur for all
while ($index < $max_size)
{
//first, everytime the loop is entered, we need the next row to be fetched

    $standings_men_inter_table = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_mens_inter);
    $standings_ladies_table = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_ladies);

//there is a high chance that the other two tables return a different row size
//so its best to check that we do not go beyond
if($index < $mens_senior_boundary)
    {
            //we fetch the rows every time we enter the block
            $standings_men_senior_table = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_mens_senior);

            //then, this is how I attempt at creating the 2 dimensional array
        array_push($standings_men_senior, array(
        $standings_men_senior_table['team_name'],
        $standings_men_senior_table['played'],
        $standings_men_senior_table['won'],
        $standings_men_senior_table['drawn'],
        $standings_men_senior_table['lost'],
        $standings_men_senior_table['for'],
        $standings_men_senior_table['against'],
        $standings_men_senior_table['points']));
    }

//incrementing index each time the loop runs
$index++;

}
```

Then finally, I just want to print what I think is the array but get this, attached image, hope you can see it clearly
[image]

Just to investigate even further, every time, the 'if' block is entered, I just commented everything out and just put this to see what was being returned

```
if($index < $mens_senior_boundary)
{
    print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_mens_senior));
}
```

The output I got was almost 90% what I need

```
Array 
([team_name] => Morley Gaels [played] => 8 [won] => 6 [drawn] => 2 
[lost] => 0 [for] => 110 [against] => 83 [points] => 14 ) 
Array ( [team_name] => Southern Districts [played] => 8 [won] => 3 [drawn] => 2 
[lost] => 3 [for] => 104 [against] => 98 [points] => 8 ) 
Array ( [team_name] => St Finbarrs [played] => 8 [won] => 3 [drawn] => 2 
[lost] => 3 [for] => 107 [against] => 99 [points] => 8 ) 
Array ( [team_name] => Western Shamrocks [played] => 8 [won] => 3 [drawn] => 0 
[lost] => 5 [for] => 96 [against] => 88 [points] => 6 ) 
Array ( [team_name] => Greenwood [played] => 8 [won] => 1 [drawn] => 1 
[lost] => 9 [for] => 82 [against] => 109 [points] => 3 )
```

What I need is for example:

```
Array(0=>Array 
([team_name] => Morley Gaels [played] => 8 [won] => 6 [drawn] => 2 
[lost] => 0 [for] => 110 [against] => 83 [points] => 14 )
1=>Array
([team_name] => Southern Districts [played] => 8 [won] => 3 [drawn] => 2 
[lost] => 3 [for] => 104 [against] => 98 [points] => 8 )..... so on);
```

My questions are

- What is wrong with my code and what is the correct way to dynamically create
  multidimensional arrays in php ?

  - Is there something I have not understood about how mysql_fetch_assoc works and how it returns ?
  - Anything to improve, anything I am doing wrong ?

I appreciate your time, than you for reading it, I tried to be as detailed as I can about what I have tried.

Thank You.

Comment: If tables' fields are similar - it's better to have one table with this fields and add field like `game(team)_type` with values `['men', 'women'...]`

Comment: Hi u_mulder, that is a good suggestion but the primary reason for having separate tables is because it is easier to get the rank this way. Later on there could be several more teams so its just easier to have 3 seperate tables and easier to rank the standings, this is just my opinion but certainly, I am looking into how I can do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

After you do this:

```
$result_mens_senior = mysqli_query($link,$get_mens_senior_query);
$result_mens_inter = mysqli_query($link,$get_mens_inter_query);
$result_ladies= mysqli_query($link, $get_ladies_query);
```

just do this

```
while ($standings_men_senior[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_mens_senior)){}
while ($standings_men_inter[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_mens_inter)){}
while ($standings_ladies[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_ladies)){}
```

Basically all of the posted code should be able to be replaced with:

```
<?php
$ladies_query = "SELECT `team_name`, `played`, `won`, `drawn`, `lost`, `for`, `against`, `points` 
FROM `standings_ladies` order by pos";

$inter_query = "SELECT `team_name`, `played`, `won`, `drawn`, `lost`, `for`, `against`, `points` 
FROM `standings_men_inter` order by pos";

$senior_query = "SELECT `team_name`, `played`, `won`, `drawn`, `lost`, `for`, `against`, `points` 
FROM `standings_men_senior` order by pos";

$ladies_stmt = mysqli_query($link, $ladies_query) || die ("Couldn't get Ladies"); // reminds me of high school
$inter_stmt  = mysqli_query($link, $inter_query)  || die ("Couldn't get Inter");
$senior_stmt = mysqli_query($link, $serior_query) || die ("Couldn't get Seniors");

$standings_men_senior = array();
$standings_men_inter = array();
$standings_ladies = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($senior_stmt)){
    $standings_men_senior[] = $row;
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($inter_stmt)){
    $standings_men_inter[] = $row;
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ladies_stmt)){
    $standings_ladies[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: I actually found the issue with my code, it actually works, it was an error on my part. I kept the print_r function inside the initial while look ($index < max) and hence it kept reprinting the array from scratch after every new addition and looking at the output.

I tried your method in a couple of ways, had a few issues, maybe I am doing it wrong

Comment: while($standings_ladies[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_ladies))
{
  $standings_ladies[]['teamname']=>$standings_ladies_table['team_name'],
  $standings_ladies[]['played']=>$standings_ladies_table['played'],
  $standings_ladies[]['won']=>$standings_ladies_table['won'],
  $standings_ladies[]['drawn']=>$standings_ladies_table['drawn'],
  $standings_ladies[]['lost']=>$standings_ladies_table['lost'],
  $standings_ladies[]['for']=>$standings_ladies_table['for'],
  $standings_ladies[]['against']=>$standings_ladies_table['against'],
  $standings_ladies[]['points']=>$standings_ladies_table['points']
}

Comment: the above gives this error Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in
I also tried the array_push($standings_ladies_inter[], array(...));, it outputted the result but also this warning on each push, array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array

Overall, I did 
while($standings_men_inter_table = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_mens_inter))
{array_push($standings_men_inter, array(..));}
This works the best.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I may have been getting too cute with the while ... see update.

Comment: Stunning solution .. replaced so many lines of code ... Thank You so much Orangepill. I am glad I decided to join stack overflow. I learn a lot from guys like you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to put everything in a single loop, it significantly reduces your code clarity and will give you little to no gain in performance, there is a term for this and it's called micro-optimization, and you should never do it unless it is really necessary (a bottleneck on a large site).

Now, what I suggest to you is to remake your loop and make it as clear as possible as to how data is manipulated.

The most important thing in your case is to debug, print_r the content of your arrays on every step of the process to check what it contains, from the database to the end of your code, you will find where the problem is.

Comment: I just looked at my code carefully again and I have done nothing wrong BUT put the print_r statement inside the while ($index < max). So the max was 7, so basically, everytime the array got a new push, I got a print_r of the newly built array, first with 1 record, then with 2, then with 3.

I then just put the print_r outside and then, absolutely nothing to be changed. This just means one thing, you are right, I do not find any performance difference, I have made 3 seperate loops, the conventional way 

while($standings_men_inter_table = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_mens_inter))

Comment: Please have a look at Orangepill's code also for other's who have a similar issue, it's well structured and how you have to go about it.